# Use of undefined constant

Tags: php

На localhost код работает, а на хостинге возникает ошибка:

> **Use of undefined constant listPages – assumed ‘listPages’**

```
$directory = $_POST['folder'];

function listPages($path, $name)
{
    global $directory;
    if (mb_substr($name, 0, 9) != 'elements-')
        return;

    echo '…';
}

listFolder($directory, ['html'], listPages);


function listFolder($folder, $allowedExts, $callback)
{
    if ($callback == null)
        return;

    $file_parts = array();
    $ext = '';
    $title = '';

    $l = strlen($folder);
    if ($l == 0  || substr($folder, $l-1, 1) != '/')
        $folder .= '/';

    $dir_handle = @opendir('../'.$folder) or die("There is an error with your directory! '$folder'");
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))
    {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
            continue;
        $file_parts = explode('.', $file);
        $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));
        $name = array_shift($file_parts);
        if (in_array($ext, $allowedExts))
            $callback($folder.$file, $name);
    }

    closedir($dir_handle);

}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: у тебя `listPages` - **функция**, а ты как константу суешь

Comment: надо так `listFolder($directory, ['html'], listPages());`

Comment: Пробовал listPages() не передаются параметры ($path, $name)

Comment: @AristarhAndrianov ну так а ты передай...

Comment: зачем передавать функцию в функцию? тем более что третий параметр не объявлен

Comment: А код listFolder() можно?

Comment: По русски нужно вопрос писать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

передавай `listPages` как строку. В отличие от *JS*, в *PHP* надо делать callback именно так:

```
function listPages($path, $name) {
    echo 'listPages function. <br/> path: '.$path.', name: '. $name;
}

function listFolder($folder, $allowedExts, $callback) {
    echo 'listFolder function. <br/><br/>';
    $callback($folder, "test.txt");
}

listFolder('/var/www/test/', ['html'], 'listPages');
```